# EXCEL search a row of dates, and return whether or not there is a date within this week

Tags: excel

I have a range of dates in a table to help me keep track of project deliverables. Each row corresponds to an individual project. How can I write a function to return whether or not there is a date in this week, either upcoming or previous?

Here is an example couple of projects:

[image]

Currently, my table tells me what the next upcoming date is. However, I would like to be able to reference that specifically to the week, tell me what projects had a deliverable this week even if it's passed.

Here is the code I'd developed to determine the next upcoming date in that row:

```
=IF(MIN(IF(D5:U5>=TODAY(),D5:U5))=0,"",MIN(IF(D5:U5>=TODAY(),D5:U5)))
```

I have the concept for returning whether or not the NEXT due date is in this week:

```
IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY()) - WEEKNUM([@[Next Due Date]]) = 0, "THIS WEEK"
```

But I don't know how to specifically craft the argument for the second weeknum() function to search the row for dates falling within this week. I don't think a vlookup returns what I want, but I could have misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking whether the dates are greater than or equal to today, you want to check whether they are greater than or equal to the first day of today's week.

The first day of today's week is

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1
```

To get the next due date that is in the current week or later:

```
=MINIFS(D2:U2,D2:U2,">="&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1)
```

And to display "THIS WEEK":

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(MINIFS(D2:U2,D2:U2,">="&TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1))=WEEKNUM(TODAY()),"This week","")
```

Comment: Thaaaaats exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this if it will satisfy your requirements?

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())=WEEKNUM(A1),"This Week",IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A1)>1,"Previous Week",IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A1)<-1,"Upcoming Week","Other Week")))
```

This formula checks the current week. If the current week minus the selected date week is less than 1, it will print "Previous Week"; if the result is greater than 1, it will print "Upcoming Week". If the current week and the selected date week is equal, it will print "This Week". If all condition are not met, it will print "Other Week".

Feel free mention me if I misunderstood the requirements, I'll do my best to modify the formula.